# Derivative of a matrix w.r.t to another?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives, matrix-calculus, machine-learning

What's the general formula for taking the derivative of a matrix w.r.t to another matrix? For example, what's $\frac{\partial A}{X}$, $\frac{\partial A}{X^\top}$, $\frac{\partial A}{\tilde{X}}$, $\frac{\partial A}{\tilde{X}^\top}$ for $A = X\tilde{X}^\top$, $A = X\tilde{X}$, $A = X^\top\tilde{X}$, and $A = X^\top\tilde{X}^\top$.

Or how about $\frac{\partial A}{X}$, $\frac{\partial A}{X^\top}$ for $A = XX^\top$, $A = X^2$, $A = X^\top X$

I struggle to derive these generally, are there known formulas for these? How do I in general go about deriving these? There are also more complicated cases of $\frac{\partial X\tilde{X}}{X^\top \tilde{X}}$ and so on.

Comment: What is the context in which you're trying to derive them, and what are you hoping to be able to do with the answers?

Comment: If you want the lazy way, the Matrix Cookbook is a good tool. Otherwise, it would require a matrix calculus basis.

Comment: Just think: which is (are) the function(s) and which are the variables. Then differentiate the function(s) w.r.t. the variables

Comment: @VanBaffo Is that an actual book? "differentiate the function(s) w.r.t. the variables" I have trouble doing that when they're vectorized. Like I just don't see how should the derivative of say $X^2$ w.r.t to X differ from $XX^\top$ w.r.t X.

Comment: Yes, that's an actual book of "rules". What I am saying is to understand what each entry of your matrix represents. If you have $\partial A / \partial X$, the entries of matrix $A$ should contain a dependence on the entries of matrix $X$

Comment: It is $\frac{\partial A}{\partial X}$, *never* $\frac{\partial A}{X}$.